# How do I change the value of a variable for a short time span?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I wanna change the value of a variable for a short time span only! If a user presses the up-key/down-key the value should be changed for 3 seconds. How could I implement this in Python?

I've tried some things such as `time.sleep()` but with this method the Tron is not moving in this time.

```py
#Controls of Tron-Bike
#Up-Key increases the forward speed
def up():
      thread_sleep_time = 0.5
    # THIS code is ONLY for the POC (proof of concept)
    # normally in TRON, the "bike" moves with a constant speed
    # therefore you can use this hook
      print("heading P1:", t1.heading())
```

I wanna change the code that the `thread_sleep_time` is set to 0.5 and after 3 seconds it should change back to 1.

Comment: Some more context about your application would be helpful. Are you running an event loop? A library or framework you're using may have some features for scheduling events -- allowing you to schedule the change to the variable for 3 seconds in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value returned by a function that checks the time elapsed and evaluates which value return.

Here an hint on how to calc the elapsed time:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically tagged [turtle-graphics], here's an approach using turtle's timer mechanism.  The method `write()` runs continuously printing the current value of `variable` to the center of the screen.  When you press the up arrow key, another timed event kicks in that changes `variable` to a different value for three seconds, after which it's restored to its original value.  The `write()` method knows nothing of this, it just keeps displaying the *current* value:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

FONT = ('Arial', 28, 'normal')

def up():
    global variable

    screen.onkey(None, "Up")  # disable handler inside handler

    screen.ontimer(lambda o=variable: reset_variable(o), 3000)  # in milliseconds

    variable = randint(1, 1000)

def reset_variable(original_value):
    global variable

    variable = original_value

    screen.onkey(up, "Up")  # restore event handler

def write():
    turtle.undo()
    turtle.write("variable = {}".format(variable), align='center', font=FONT)
    screen.ontimer(write, 250)

variable = randint(1, 1000)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.write("variable = {}".format(variable), align='center', font=FONT)

screen.onkey(up, "Up")
screen.listen()

write()

screen.mainloop()
```